# Properly seeding a RNG for a card game

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, playing-cards, mersenne-twister

I'm working on a card game and I need the shuffle algorithm to do a very good job and to be different every time the game runs and to not have predictable card sequences.

I'm using the Mersenne twister algorithm but it still needs a seed, so really, although it produces great numbers, right now there are only 1000 possible sequences of games since I'm using time(NULL) to seed. How should I be seeding?

Comment: Why does using time(NULL) mean you only have 1000 possibilities?

Comment: @SoapBox  If I walways seed with 678, the games will always be exactly the same, and time(NULL) returns a value from 1 to 1000

Comment: As you know, there are only 1000 possible values for a `time_t`... ;)

Comment: `time(NULL)` returns the *current time* in seconds since January 1, 1970 GMT. The value of `time(NULL)` has been greater than `1000` for decades, and increases once per second. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My standard seeding technique:

1. If `/dev/urandom` exists, read a seed from there.
2. If you're in Windows, use `CryptGenRandom()`.
3. If all else fails, use `time()`.

(Not sure where your Mersenne twister comes from, but there new standard library has one in `<random>` which integrates very elegantly.)

I'm happy to hear suggestions for platforms that aren't covered by the first two steps!

Comment: Well, one could always plug a shortwave radio antenna into the serial port and read random bits of atmospheric noise... ;)

Comment: I would avoid coding option 3 into your code at all for anything where there's money at stake - you don't want to be accidentally and unknowingly generating predictable random numbers!

Comment: Nick: Well, it's all a trade-off. If there's money riding on this, I'm sure you know what your platform will be, so you can find a suitable source of randomness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [operating system's entropy source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) to get a good random number seed. On Windows, that's [CryptoAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI); on POSIX, pull bytes from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Note that reading from `/dev/random` may block, especially if you're running a lot of simultaneous copies of your process.

Comment: Four bytes isn't nearly enough. The mersenne twister has a much bigger internal state, and there are 52! ~= 2^225 possible ways to shuffle a deck.

Comment: @Kerrek Indeed - and `/dev/urandom` should be cryptographically secure and perfectly sufficient in modern kernels.

Comment: Nick: the MT in `<random>` (all engines, for that matter) seed from a value that's only as big as their result type, i.e. `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Not really; see 26.5.1.2 **Seed sequence** requirements.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, thanks, I had forgotten about that. Indeed, you *can* also seed from sequences (though you don't have to). Very good point!

Answer (score 0):

A typical seed value is the low 32 bits in a 64 bit current time. For example Use the return value of Linux gettimeofday call.